# how to exclude zero from the range

Tags: java, integer, range, dice

I am learning Java, at a very beginning level. I am trying to print the Dice result, so from 1 to 6.

```
//instance of random class
Random DICE = new Random();

int DiceRange = 7;


int RIGHT = DICE.nextInt(DiceRange);
int LEFT = DICE.nextInt(DiceRange);


System.out.println("Right Dice = " + RIGHT);
System.out.println("Left Dice = " + LEFT);
```

The issue with this code that "Zero" is also printed sometimes. I want to keep the range from 1 to 6, instead of 0 to 6. 
I tried to do the following, but did not work:

```
int i = 0;

while (DiceRange == 0); {
    i++;
}
```

The CPU went to 100% :)

So how to exclude zero from this?

Comment: Fix the upper limit of the range to 6 instead of 7 (generates a number between 0 and 5) and just add 1 to the result. That `while` doesn't make much sense anyway.

Comment: Does this ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/363691/133203) answer in particular) answer your question? [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)

Comment: the while would theroretically work (albeit still being silly) if you didn't put the semicolon after the condition. that just makes an infinite loop `while (DiceRange == 0);`, followed by an unreachable scoped codeblock `{ i++; }`

Comment: @Felk that wouldn't be the only problem. How would incrementing `i` make `DiceRange` not 0?

Comment: just an english thing: "dice" = plural "die" = singular ;-)

Answer (score 2):

From [Random documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-):

> public int nextInt(int bound)
>
> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0
>   (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

So starting from your code you can solve your problem using :

```
Random DICE = new Random();
int DiceRange = 6;
int RIGHT = DICE.nextInt(DiceRange) + 1;
int LEFT = DICE.nextInt(DiceRange) + 1;
```

Comment: I am still getting Zero, even with +2, + 3, but I also get high numbers like 7, 8 ,,

Comment: System.out.println("Right Dice = " + (RIGHT + 1));
this one worked

Comment: @MohammedHashim You are right, my ide added automatically parenthesis, it is ok now.